# AppEngine GWT-RPC service serving for Web as well as Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt-rpc

Folks,

I have GWT-RPC services (on Appengine) supporting a GWT Web client. All is well.

Now, when I am developing an Android Client for this, do I need a stripped down Servlet to serve this client? Meaning, Now instead of Serialized Java objects sent back and forth (as in GWT), I will need to send XML using Android's packaged HttpClient to a new Servlet (which can possibly reuse the GWT-RPC services within the AppEngine).

Am I on track here? Does Android allow for GWT-RPC service backends directly?

I am trying to be succinct from a code perspective..

Answer (score 1):

GWT-RPC is an opaque, non-standard protocol, designed for use in GWT apps only. AFAIK there is no mechanism for communicating in GWT-RPC in any other environment (e.g., Android) or language (e.g., Python, PHP).

GWT-RPC is not optimal as a reusable multi-platform RPC mechanism because of this.

For communicating with an Android client I suggest [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), which are designed to be compact and multi-platform. Unfortunately there is not currently support for sending PBs to GWT clients.

You could also use regular JSON, in either [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) or [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) flavors, which can be consumed by either GWT or Android clients, and is fairly compact, at least compared to XML.